# Kerberos Bootstrap error with ldap

Tags: openldap, mitkerberos

Up until recently I have had no issues deploying Kerberos with an LDAP backend for the database.  Recently however I have started to get this error when trying to generate the password stash file which allows the krb5kdc to talk to slapd:

```
kdb5_ldap_util: Unable to find requested database type while setting up lib handle
```

I am not 100% certain, but I believe this may be an issue with loading the ldap database library in kdb5_ldap_util.  I have confirmed that my version of Kerberos was built with ldap support, so I'm reasonably sure that isn't the issue.  I'm also reasonably sure that I am the last one to modify the distro's package build script so ldap should be enabled in the build.

I am currently using kerberos 1.14.2 and slapd 2.4.44.  I would rather not downgrade as doing so would mean not using official packages.

Has anyone else ever run into such an issue or know of an alternative way to build the initial stash file?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that the error message did not relate to the error in my case.  I just had to set the default realm and then everything worked.

To be clear to anyone else running into this error in the future:
Make sure that you have default_realm defined in either krb5.conf or kdc.conf, or by DNS if your site uses that (though its still a good idea to have it in kdc.conf while bootstrapping).